# Android Permission Error Even with declaration in manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am trying to open an intent to choose a photo from the android gallery and then set an image view in the parent activity with the chosen image. I am able to open gallery and choose and image but then the parent activity crashes in the onActivityResult() method. The crash occurs in the Cursor instantiation line.

```
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Parent Activity on Result method

```
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        if(!isExternalStorageReadable()) {
            Log.d("NAMSD", "SS");
        } else {
            Log.d("hey", selectedImage.toString());

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};


            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            cursor.close();

            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

            photo.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
```

Stach Trace:

> 02-16 16:09:54.108 1803-1815/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
>                                                   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/37 from pid=8382, uid=10057 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
>   02-16 16:09:54.108 8382-8382/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   02-16 16:09:54.109 8382-8382/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: io.github.getExposure, PID: 8382
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/37 }} to activity {io.github.getExposure/io.github.getExposure.PostViewActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/37 from pid=8382, uid=10057 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/37 from pid=8382, uid=10057 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>                                                        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
>                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
>                                                        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
>                                                        at io.github.getExposure.PostViewActivity.onActivityResult(PostViewActivity.java:135)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Does your app target 23?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but I suspect you are compiling with android-23 API (Marshmallow) and It has introduced the new way of asking the user for permission on the spot of using it, so have two choices

1. (**Recommended**) Ask the user for that permission before using it. More info
   [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).
2. (**NOT recommended**) Change you target API to a pre-Marshmallow version and that reverts to the old way of asking about all the permissions on application installation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    permissions = new String[2];
    permissions[0] = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    permissions[1] = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            permissions,
            5
    );
```

I just needed to explicitly ask for permission to read/write external storage in my activity because of android marshmallow.